# Stripe authorize a charge and send to the connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am authorizing a charge and i can see that in stripe dashboard logs

```
$token = $request->request->get('stripeToken');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_vnd8ISCnXoSnW3b');
$data = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 9 * 100,
    "currency" => "gbp",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "First test charge!",
    "capture" => false
));
```

Now i want to be able to send this charge after couple of days via cron job to the connected account.

I can setup the cron job thats not a problem, the problem is how can i create a charge for this? The documentation says all I have to do is as following

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_vnd8ISCnXoSnW3b");

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'gbp',
  'source' => {TOKEN},
  'destination' => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
));
```

but i am not able to understand what this **TOKEN** is that I need to pass?

Please note that this transaction is being made couple of days after the payment has been authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not certain but I think you can't do like that, the charge usually is ment for customer charge (credit cards, bitcoins etc.), if you want to transfare money to the connected account, you should do that in the first charge this "'destination' => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}" should be in the first charge, then when you capture money will go automaticly. Anyway if you still want to transfare between accounts you should consider using managed accounts, there you have more freedom do manage you money self.
Please refer to: https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge what charges does and here for connected accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform